# EMMC not Detected! SP Flash Tool

Tags: android, rom, flash-memory

I recently successfully flashed Stock Rom on my MMX A46. Now I am trying to flash it again. It won't, rather it stucks on Downloading DA with red Bar on 100% and wont even move after 4:00 min.

Memory Test Report:

```
Internal RAM:

Size = 0x00020000 (128KB)

External RAM:

Type = DRAM

Size = 0x10000000 (256MB/2048Mb)

NAND Flash:

Device ID = "[TOSHIBA] TYBC0A111557KC" (115)
Size = 0x20000000 (512MB/4096Mb)

EMMC :

ERROR: EMMC was not detected!
```

The things I done to my ROM:

I tried to install a custom rom made for mt6572 but it gave error while installing through CTR(Recovery).Later I saw its updator Script and it formatted /System and /Data to format("ext4","EMMC",blah,blah); but my phone was supposed to be formatted with "UBIFS " and "MTD".

Comment: Is this even a real programming question? Looks like hardware assistance